# Usage of "desde" and "de"

Tags: preposiciones

When are `desde` and `de` used? `Desde` and `de` both mean "from", but in what context are they used?

1. Estoy corriendo **desde** la puerta al cuarto de mi nieto Paulo.
2. **De** Barcelona le escribe una carta a su novia Juana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Desde' implies the start of an extent of time or space, and there is always an implied 'hasta' (to). So you can run from 10:00 to 10:15 ("Correr desde las 10 hasta las 10:15") or, as in your example, "hasta el cuarto de mi nieto Paulo".

On the other hand, 'De' does not imply a start but an origin. So your second example would not be correct, it would be again 'desde' since there is a space extent from Barcelona to the place where Juana is: "Le escribe una carta a su novia Juana desde Barcelona".

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'desde' or 'de' when you're speaking about some point in space.

```
Estoy corriendo desde la puerta al cuarto de mi nieto Paulo.
Estoy corriendo de la puerta al cuarto de mi nieto Paulo.
```

or

```
De Barcelone le escribe una carta a su novia Juana.
Desde Barcelone le escribe una carta a su novia Juana.
```

But remember that only you an use them that way when you're speaking about some point in space.

Comment: 'Desde' can also be used when you're speaking about some point in time. For example: `Juego a baloncesto desde el año 2010` to say `I play basketball since 2013`

Comment: @mornaner of course, but then you can not use 'de' in there, just because 'desde' does not refer to a point in place, maybe I didn't explained too well to keep that clearly, that was refering space not time. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

A key difference between 'de' and 'desde' is:

'de' can be used as 'of' where 'desde' can't:  El ultimo dia de el mes' (The Last day of the month)

But many times 'de' is used as short for 'desde' :'Vinieron De el Norte' (They came From the North)

'Desde' cannot be used instead of 'de' when denoting possession or belonging:
'La libertad de expresion' (The freedom of speech) But not 'La libertad desde expresion'
'El color de el cielo' (the color of the sky) But Not 'El color desde el cielo'